# is it possible to do sql injection in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, sql-injection

I have a searchbox and where I am submitting the text like java, etc and based on that I am finding the rhe data through GORM like given code:

```
def searchQueryInSession = params?.searchQuery
def searchSkill = MetaSkills.findAllByName(searchQueryInSession)
```

Is it possible to do sql injection here? If yes then, how can we prevent this behaviour in the described scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: **no**

GORM will create the query with binding parameters similar to the following one:

```
select m.* from meta_skills m where name = ?
```

so, it can't alter your program and do any harm.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @mkuligowski
So this way I am doing is fine?

Comment: @NarendraSharma according to sql-injection it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

One caveat is that you need to be careful when doing HQL.  It is possible to write an injection attack using HQL, such as

```
def vulnerable() {
    def books = Book.find("from Book as b where b.title ='" + params.title + "'")
}
```

or

```
def vulnerable() {
    def books = Book.find("from Book as b where b.title ='${params.title}'")
}
```

Examples taken from: [Grails Documentation - Security](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.2/guide/security.html)